# Horizontal UIStackView stretching subview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swift-playground

I have the following playground and can't figure out why the ImageView width constraing is not being respected and it fills the remaining space on the StackView

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 800))

let imageView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

let navBarHeaderStackView = UIStackView()
navBarHeaderStackView.distribution = .equalCentering
navBarHeaderStackView.alignment = .center
navBarHeaderStackView.axis = .horizontal
navBarHeaderStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
//navBarHeaderStackView.addArrangedSubview(titlesStackView)

view.addSubview(navBarHeaderStackView)
navBarHeaderStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

navBarHeaderStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
navBarHeaderStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
navBarHeaderStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
navBarHeaderStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

navBarHeaderStackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `trailingAnchor` to `lessThanOrEqualTo` insted of `equalTo`.

```
navBarHeaderStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of this constraint

```
navBarHeaderStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

comment it and try